# click and addclass again after class has been added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

as the title says I want to add classes to a div without using toggle.'

so basically I want to add a class to a footer, I can achieve this by using:

```
$('footer').click(function(){
   $('footer').addClass('class-one');
});
```

but the problem is that I want to add a class again by clicking once more while class-one exist

then again just adding

```
$('.class-one').click(function(){
     $('.class-one').addClass('class-two');
     $('.class-two').removeClass('class-one');
});

repeat this

$('.class-two').click(function(){
    $('.class-two).addClass('class-three');
    $('.class-three).removeClass('class-two);
```

doesn't work.

can someone tell me how I can achieve my goal? so i can repeat this like 5~9times?

If my question is hard to understand 
what Im trying to do is that

imagine Im clicking

picture of a ball and I click it so that it turns into triangle

when I click triangle it turns into a square

and I click it again and it turns into a hexagon

Comment: Can you share your html code also. Are these `class-one`,`class-two`... div or footer tags? It will be better if you can share a jsfiddle link with your problem statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your classes in an `Array` and then use an index to access the class and also make use of a counter which will act as our index in this case, which we will update using increment operator.

```
var classes = ["class-one", "class-two"], counter = 0;
$('footer').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass(classes[counter]).addClass(classes[counter++]);
});
```

Comment: I think you need to remove previously added class and then add new class.

Comment: Wow, it works!!!. Thank you I've been struggling alone hours and hours and thought I would give stackoverflow a shot you guys responded really fast!

Comment: One more thing is there way to share my source codes so people can see this question in action?

Comment: @Paul you could create a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

*Eg:*

```
$('.one').click(function(e)
{
    $(e.currentTarget).removeClass('one');
    $(e.currentTarget).addClass('two');
});
```

Refer: http://jsfiddle.net/3uz03b5r/

**Your Code:**

```
$('.class-one').click(function(e){
     $(e.currentTarget).addClass('class-two');
     $(e.currentTarget).removeClass('class-one');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x1kn7p8q/11/)

Try this one

Html

```
<div class = "set0">Test<div>
```

Jquery

```
var i = 0;
$('.set'+i).on('click',function(){
    $(this).removeClass('set'+i);
    i++;
   $(this).addClass('set'+i);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this..**

```
<div id="facts">
<p>(click me):</p>
<input type="hidden" class="old" value="0"/>
  <div class="class-1"><div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var current = 1;
    $('#facts').click(function() {
     var old= $(".old").val();
      var newvalue= parseInt(current)+parseInt(old); 
$(".old").val(newvalue);      
    $('.class-'+old).addClass('class-'+newvalue);
   $('.class-'+newvalue).removeClass('class-'+old);

    });
});
</script>
```